# how can I place my sidebar navigation links and icons in the middle of my sidebar

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, sidebar

i am new to HTML and CSS so im still learning the ropes.
I would like to place my sidebar navigation links and icons in the centre of my navigation bar, as well as allow my navigation bar to turn into a drop-down menu once the site is opened on a smaller screened device. Also if you see any errors in my code or any way I can improve it please feel free to let me know, any advice would be very appreciated

```
      <body>
        <header>
          <div id="Sidebar">
            <div class="nav-links">
              <h2>Omar Mahmoud</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="home"><em class="fa-solid fa-house"></em> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="about-me"
                    ><em class="fa-solid fa-user"></em> About Me</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="what-i-do"
                    ><em class="fa-solid fa-user"></em> What I do</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="portfolio"
                    ><em class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></em> Portfolio</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="contact"
                    ><em class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></em> Contact</a
                  >
                </li>
              </ul>

              <div class="social-media">
                <a href="github"><em class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></em></a>
                <a href="Linkedin"><em class="fa-brands fa-github"></em></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </body>
```

`h2 {`
`font-family: "Alegreya Sans SC", sans-serif;`
`font-size: 30px;`
`}`
`.nav-links {`
`font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;`
`}`

`.fa-brands {`
`color: white;`
`}`
`.fa-brands:hover {`
`color: blue;`
`}`

- `{`
  `margin: 0;`
  `padding: 0;`
  `}`

`header {`
`position: fixed;`
`width: 10%;`
`height: 100%;`
`background-color: black;`
`}`

`li,`
`a {`
`text-decoration: none;`
`font-size: 20px;`
`}`

`.nav-links {`
`list-style: none;`
`}`

`.nav-links li {`
`list-style: none;`
`padding-top: 15px;`
`margin-top: 5%;`
`margin-left: 25%;`
`}`

`.nav-links li a {`
`color: White;`
`}`

`.nav-links li a:hover {`
`color: Blue;`
`}`

`.social-media:hover {`
`color: red;`
`}`

`.social-media {`
`display: block;`
`}`

`.social-media {`
`margin-top: 40px;`
`margin-left: 35%;`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by removing

```
margin-left: 25%;
```

from the ".nav-links li" selector css.

I would continue by considering a fixed width for your sidebar. This will make it easier to find a solution for centering the nav-links.

I would also consider using flex https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp to arrange the links.